# Shutdown Spring Integration's async pub-sub channel threads immediately when container receives a SIG_TERM

Tags: spring-integration

I am facing an issue where my spring integration project is trying to sftp something, but when the PaaS needs to restart my container, I need to stop everything, do some cleanup tasks quickly and let it dies.

So I would need to already-executing pub-sub async channel thread to stop immediately (the sftp task) so it won't cause racing condition with the SmartLifeCycle's stop().  I wonder if there is anyway I can achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: I wonder what made you think that there is a race condition. All those Polling Channel Adapters are really stopped gracefully when `container.stop()` is initiated. Please, be more specific what is wrong going on in your  case.

Comment: Sorry I was out of town..

The app was built as a scheduled job where files are sftp to the remote server, then a ready file with the successfully transmitted files were generated and sftp to the same remote directory.

But when shutdown happens, I need to quickly send an empty ready file to the remote server and let the app dies.  But I noticed some of the service activators were still running after the empty ready file was sent, so I need a way to also stop that thread immediately before the empty ready file transmission.